# SVG: drawing inside a child element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working with d3.js library and need to draw some svg elements inside another child svg element. For example, I have a container element in the svg, which is a "rect". I want too draw some lines inside that "rect". But I am having issue viewing those lines.

If I add those line to the main svg container, it works fine. But the lines are not visible when I am adding those to the "rect". I guess, coordinate is the issue.

So, can anyone let me know, how the coordinate should be calculated while drawing inside a child element? Is it automatically offset by it's parent coordinate? or the "rect" will have it's own coordinate system?

Comment: I am presuming that you are appending the SVG as child DOM of the `rect` in such case it will not be displayed.
Add the new SVG within the main SVG it will display.

Comment: In my case, I have only one svg. The hierarchy goes like this (parent to child): svg->border(a rect)-> the lines (which are not getting displayed).
However, if the hierarchy goes like that, svg->border and svg->lines, it works.

Comment: Exactly! svg->border(a rect)-> the lines  this will never work...if you make svg lines inside rect DOM it will never get displayed. If you want to show the lines are within the rectangle you need to draw accordingly translate or give proper x and y to the line. Your concept of making line dom inside rectangle dom will make the lines appear inside  is wrong...SVG does not work like that.

Comment: Okay understood. Thanks. I am adding another question regarding rendering. Will post the link here for your consider to explain. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: He is my new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738746/svg-how-to-draw-graph-elements-that-will-be-crop-outside-a-rectangular-area

Answer (score 4):

`<line>` is not rendered inside a `<rect>`.

If you look at https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElement, only animation and descriptive elements are allowed as contents of `<rect>`

You might want to restructure your code to use the `g` element as a container element for grouping together related graphics elements (such as `<rect>` and `<line>`).

If you need to position the grouping element, you can use a transform.

```
<svg width="1000" height="500">
  <g transform="translate(10,30)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" style="fill:black;"></rect>
    <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="20" y2="20" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></line>
    <line x1="40" y1="0" x2="40" y2="20" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></line>
    <line x1="60" y1="0" x2="60" y2="20" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></line>
    <line x1="80" y1="0" x2="80" y2="20" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></line>
  </g>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ksav/wq6mvv9v/