# svg: how to draw graph elements that will be crop outside a rectangular area

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to render gantt chart using d3.js and svg.
The chart has two part, one (the mini chart) display the complete gantt chart.
Other (the main chart) display only partial of the chart.

I have a view window in in the mini chart  which I can drag over the mini chart.
Now the main chart is supposed to render only the portion inside the view widow (main chart works as a zoomed version of the mini chart).

Now I need to render the data in the main chart which is bordered by a "rect".
How can I crop the elements that goes outside that main chart area?

Adding another svg as the inside the main svg could be a solution. Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: can u post a working fiddle...

Comment: You crop things with a clip or a clipPath

Comment: This is not exact code as my actual code is very large and part of a large project, but this fiddle shows what I wan to achieve, https://jsfiddle.net/pixelord/ttk486fk/#&togetherjs=nB5HCq8Nrj 

I want all the chart elements to crop if those cose outside the rectangle area.

Comment: Did you try d3.brush? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

Answer (score 5):

You can use [clipPath](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/clip-path.html).

Sample Code

```
svg.append("clipPath") // define a clip path
  .attr("id", "rect-clip") // give the clipPath an ID
  .append("rect") //Append the shape for clipping
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("width", 420)
  .attr("height", 260)
  .attr("fill", "#ccffff");

var chartElem1 = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 50)
  .attr("cy", 80)
  .attr("r", 40)
  .attr("fill", "#ffccff")
  .attr("fill-opacity", 0.6)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)"); //Set clip-path using id
```

```js
var dataset = {
  apples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
};

var width = 460,
  height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("background-color", "grey");

svg.append("clipPath") // define a clip path
  .attr("id", "rect-clip") // give the clipPath an ID
  .append("rect") //Append the shape for clipping
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("width", 420)
  .attr("height", 260)
  .attr("fill", "#ccffff");

var chartContainer = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("width", 420)
  .attr("height", 260)
  .attr("fill", "#ccffff");

var chartElem1 = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 50)
  .attr("cy", 80)
  .attr("r", 40)
  .attr("fill", "#ffccff")
  .attr("fill-opacity", 0.6)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)");

var chartElem2 = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 200)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "#ffccff")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)");
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```